# Xcode 4 Error: "the view outlet was not set"

Tags: iphone, view, xcode4, outlet

I'm starting to program using Xcode/iOS
I've been reading some books and tutorial...
For my first application, I tried to do a "Hello World"
I did the program following every single step in the right way, but when I run the application, the program crash...
I read some posts to find the solution, but even when I check or do the steps that the posts suggest, I still have the same error. I tried to do another project, but the result is always the same.
This the capture of my screen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your "View reference outlet to files owner" by dragging the link
from "Views" to "File's Owner" in your nib. I think that's why you are getting
the crash:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. I already did and have thus, but I still have the same error. My application crash

Comment: Oh! so did you reach at any conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Class of File Owner to your ViewController,
Then set the View Outlet Again..!!

If it doesn't work, delete the view and drag a new one from Library. Set File Owner and View outlet again.